# SQL split columns to rows after using union

Tags: sql, union, rows

My table

```
+-----------+---------+
|    Date   |  Letter |
+-----------+---------+
| 13.02.2013|    B    |
| 01.03.2016|    A    |
| 28.12.2003|    C    |
| 12.01.2017|    B    |
| 25.04.2011|    A    |
+-----------+---------+
```

I created a query which returns right data, but not as expected:

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT TOP 1 Date as Date1, Letter as Letter1 from TAB where
Letter = 'A'
order by Date DESC
) TAB
UNION
SELECT * from
(
SELECT TOP 1 Date as Date2, Letter as Letter2 from TAB where 
Letter = 'B'
order by Datum DESC
) TAB
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
|    Date1  | Letter1 |    Date2  | Letter2 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 01.03.2016|    A    | 12.01.2017|    B    |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+---------+
|    Date1  | Letter1 |
+-----------+---------+
| 01.03.2016|    A    | 
| 12.01.2017|    B    |
+-----------+---------+
```

Is it possible get all 4 rows like expected using UNION?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want the "A"s and the "B"s in lists in columns.  This is not really a relational output, because the columns in a row have no relationship to each other.  But, you can do it using conditional aggregation:
TOP 1 Date as Date1, Letter as Letter1

```
select max(case when letter = 'A' then date end) as date1,
       'A' as letter1,
       max(case when letter = 'B' then date end) as date2,
       'B' as letter2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by letter order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where letter in ('A', 'B')
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you very much. Your solutions works perfect. I also added ID to it and im getting what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the second query to (as date 1 and as letter1 ) the columns  have to be the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `join` instead of `union all` for the two sub queries and call the columns from both the sub queries using `alias`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result on the same row you need  a join (not an union) eg:

```
SELECT T1.Date, T1.Letter, T2.date, T2.Letter 
from  (
    SELECT TOP 1 '1' as id,  Date , Letter 
    from TAB 
    where Letter = 'A'
    order by Date DESC
) T1
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT TOP 1  '1' as id, Date , Letter  
  from TAB 
  where   Letter = 'B'
  order by Datum DESC
) T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood your problem correctly.

Please check below query.

```
select Date1 , Letter1 , Date2 , Letter2
from
(SELECT TOP 1 Date as Date1, Letter as Letter1 from TAB where
Letter = 'A'
order by Date DESC) a join 
(
SELECT TOP 1 Date as Date2, Letter as Letter2 from TAB where 
Letter = 'B'
order by Date DESC
) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not what UNION does. It simply combines the given two data sets into one, as you can see in your example. You could try to use a CASE like in this answer: [SQL - Query same column twice with different dates in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100150/sql-query-same-column-twice-with-different-dates-in-where-clause)